# Get Image from Android gallery to C#

Tags: c#, android, image, unity-game-engine

I'm creating an android app in Unity(I'm coding in C#), I'm nearly done just need to add some final tweaks for it to make sense. Currently I'm having trouble with getting a profile picture for users profile. I would like that when a user presses a button his android gallery opens and when he chooses a picture it is displayed in the app, and sent to database. So something like this

```
public Button ChangeImage;
public Image ProfilePicture;

void Start()
{
    ChangeImage.onClick.AddListener(ChangeImageClicked);
}

void ChangeImageClicked()
{
    //here gallery would open and selected image would be returned
    //ProiflePicture = ChoosenImage
}
```

I googled for a solution for about a week now but didn't manage to find it. I read about Intents but C# doesn't recognise them. All help will be greatly apriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various plugins that handle this for you nicely. One of them is [NativeGalery](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeGallery). 
I have used it myself for a project.

A snippet from my code:

```
public Image LocalProfileImage;

public void ShowMediaPicker()
{
    if (Application.isEditor)
    {
        // Do something else, since the plugin does not work inside the editor
    }
    else
    {
        NativeGallery.GetImageFromGallery((path) =>
        {
            UploadNewProfileImage(path);
            Texture2D texture = NativeGallery.LoadImageAtPath(path);
            if (texture == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                return;
            }

            LocalProfileImage.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.zero);
        });
    }
}
```

The `UploadNewProfileImage(path);` is a function of mine that sends the image to a database. Basically you should retrieve the image from the path and then convert it into bytes using a streamreader.

Comment: Thank you so much. At first it didn't work because i forgot to uncomment calling of function. But now it works. This is exactly what I've spent hours loking for. Thanks again.