# Path and gallery

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a problem with my gallery code, my Android does not recognize the right folder with the .jpg images on the line 20 and 30. It´s a lot different that a PC code cause of the disk details, if someone could help me, i will be a lot gratefull

```
 public class Gallery : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<Sprite> gallery = new List<Sprite>();
    public Image displayImage;
    public Button nextImg;
    public Button prevImg;
    public int i = 0;

    void Start ()
    {
        // var Images = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Bandeira/Downloads/Menu Start/Assets/Sprite/JPG/","*.jpg");
        var Images = Directory.GetFiles("file:///" + "/unitypictures/","*.jpg");
        Debug.Log(Images);
        StartCoroutine(LoadImages(Images));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadImages(string[] Images)
    {
        foreach (var path in Images)
        {
            Debug.Log(path);
            using (var uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture("file:///" + path))
            // using (var uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(path))
            {
                Debug.Log(path);
                yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
            
                if (uwr.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
                {
                    Debug.Log(uwr.error);
                    yield break;
                }
            
                var tex = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
                    
                var sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0f, 0f, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 50f, 0, SpriteMeshType.FullRect);
                gallery.Add(sprite);
                uwr.Dispose();
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    public void BtnNext (){
        if(i + 1 < gallery.Count){
            i++;
        }
        displayImage.sprite = gallery[i];
    }
 
    public void BtnPrev () {
        if (i - 1 > 0){
            i--;
        }
        displayImage.sprite = gallery[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: As we said yesterday. Android does not use c: it is not windows. So no. It will not find anything starting c:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Image from Android gallery to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465517/get-image-from-android-gallery-to-c-sharp)

Comment: I am not using anything with C disk, i have tried with perssistents assests, and still nothing

Answer (score 1):

Dude, I already told you yesterday.
You are using absolute paths, and they cannot work, because for each operating system they are different.
If you connect your Android phone to your computer, or install a file manager, you can see that there should be no folder called "UnityPictures", and even if there is you can't get there easily because I believe they are protected by the device.
The answer is always the same: you can use Persistent data path to save the images and resume them later.
For example you can save them in the Directory (Application.PersistentDataPath + "UnityPictures") and get them back from the same path.
So to be clear: you have to create the folder and insert those images, if you then want to download them.
Alternatively you can also download them from a server. So you could edit them, add more, or remove them without the need for updates, and it would be usable for all devices.

Comment: I really apreciate your help,but the persistent data path didn´t work yesterday, so i "respost" de problem

Comment: Why didn't it work? Are you sure you didn't make a mistake in using the resource?

Comment: I am not shure, but the images are being saved, however, the app can´t get them

Comment: Where are they saved? Who and when saves the images? How do you save the images?

Comment: Here you have the code, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dNgkvzkvY-woCzr1TfsBqUWom4fxY5Mj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Right now its not using a Persistent Path, but i have already tried it and it doenst work